# Bootstrap progress bar to grow when it is shown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

When I open the collapsed container that my Bootstrap progress bar is in, I'd like to have the progress bar grow to its actual percentage in a sort of quick animation, to add a nice effect to the app I'm working on.

The progress bar uses a % width to show the progress, I want that width to grow from 0 to its destined percentage. I plan to set a click event on the collapse toggle which will handle that, and have an event fire every x milliseconds until it reaches the destined percentage once the collapse toggle it clicked to show the contents of the container.

Comment: Congratulations. What have you tried to do? Have you bothered researching animating a width with CSS? I'm pretty sure it's a simple thing

Comment: The important answer is that Bootstrap already uses CSS3 animations, and dynamically changing the width animates the change on its own. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/48bu5/